# How to include fixes to an open source pacakge in my node.js project?

Tags: git, npm, open-source

For my node.js application after git clone other developers can currently npm install, npm start to get up and running with no other steps.

One of our dependencies which is open source on github (and we currently install through npm) has a bug that affects us. I put an issue on github but have not heard anything back and the project has not been actively maintained for a while.

What is the usual way people deal with this? Should I clone the project on github, implement my fix and release my own npm package for my fork? Or is it better practice to apply a patch to files that come down after npm install?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to publishing your own version of the package to `npm` is to add a git URL instead of npm package version to the dependency section of `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "some_package": "git://github.com/user/project.git"
  }
}
```

It's what I sometimes do while waiting for my pull requests to be accepted. In some cases you can even point the package to a local path on your hard disk:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "some_package": "../some/package"
  }
}
```

Though obviously this would require a manual means of distributing the fixed version of the package like email or dropbox or a thumb drive.

See the docs for more options: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

My general rule of thumb is, if my patch don't get accepted after a year then I'll just publish my own version of the package on npm.